# How to save soft-keyboard open when edittext is not focused

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have an EditText and SwitchCompat inside the ScrollView. When the EditText recieve a focus, I want to show soft-keyboard, and when I touch the ScrollView keyboard should remain open.
I use this code:

```
et_phone_input.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, b ->
            if (b) {
                setFocusAndShowKeyboard2(editText, requireContext())
            } 
        }

fun setFocusAndShowKeyboard2(view : View, context: Context){
    view.requestFocus()
    val imm: InputMethodManager =
        ContextCompat.getSystemService(context, Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
}
```

It works good in API 27, but does not work for API 28, 29, 30.

Even I use the `InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORSED`, when I swith the SwithCompat widget keyboard hides.
I try to use     `imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY)`, but there is anoter problem: when I leave a Fragment and show the Dialog - keyboard stay.
Is that possible to fix it?

**UPDATE**: added xml layout file of the screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin16">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:flow_verticalAlign="center"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                style="@style/TextMainHeader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/login_header"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_agreement_points"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin4"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header_your_phone"
                style="@style/TextMainHeader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:text="@string/header_your_phone"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rv_agreement_points" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_phone_input"
                style="@style/TextPhone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin8"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_r8"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/input_inactive"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="+7"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header_your_phone"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phone_error"
                style="@style/TextSmallError"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin4"
                android:text="Номер должен начинаться на +79 или +77"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_phone_input" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/links"
                style="@style/TextTertiary"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin16"
                android:textColorLink="@color/brand"
                android:text="Я соглашаюсь на обработку персональных данных, с политикой конфиденциальности и условиями сервиса "
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/switch_agreement"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_phone_input"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.73" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/empty_space"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/links"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/switch_agreement"
                style="@style/MySwitch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:minHeight="48dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/links"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/links"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/links" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/background">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_take_code"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/take_code"
            style="@style/MyButton"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and part of Fragment code. According to the designer's idea, if the user clicks on the input, the screenView scrolls up. Maybe, problem is there.

```
input.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, b ->
    if (b) {
        setFocusAndShowKeyboard2(input, requireContext())
        isInputClicked.postValue(true)
        input.setBackgroundTintList(
            ContextCompat.getColorStateList(
                requireContext(),
                R.color.input_active
            )
        )
    } 
}

isInputClicked.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    if (it) {
        var errorTimer = object: CountDownTimer(50L, 10L) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                if (millisUntilFinished < 400L) {
                }
            }
            override fun onFinish() {
                scrollView.postDelayed(Runnable() {
                    run() {
                        scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN)
                    }
                }, 200)
            }
        }.start()

    }
})
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the xml layout of the fragment/activity with that ScrollView, Switch and EditText?

Comment: @marcinP Done. Also I added the part of Fragment code.

Comment: I copy-pasted your xml layout to an empty project and wasn't able to reproduce your issue on api28, when I scrolled that scrollView manually. Does this happen only when you scroll programmatically or also manually? Also, this RecyclerView nested in your ScrollView doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: @marcinP The main problem is not about scroll, it is about using SwithCompat widget and EditText. I want to keyboard not to close, when I touch the switch. Is this happend in your project? About RecyclerView - I now, it is not a perfect idea, in previous version of code there were a TextView. But this RecyclerView is non-scrolable, it is for data, wich we take from server just one time.